# Magento1.9 : Few questions about Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, module, email, cache, backup

- Can I create a full system backup and expect the site to still be running efficiently ? I know there is an option to not disable the site while backup is in progress, But what will happen if leave the site open?
- I have no contact with the previous developers so I don't know of the changes that have been done to the site such as js, CSS customization. So I'm a little afraid to upgrade the modules. Could it override current custom settings? And where can I expect these to located?
- When I try to customize js files(scripts.js in public_html/js), the changes are not shown. I guess this is a caching issue. I've tried to flush both the Magento cache and cache storage, even `updated/disabled/enabled` the cache types and also entered the site in private mode so that the browser cache is reset. Nothing. However, it does seem to show after a couple of hours.
- I am not receiving order confirmation emails and this includes invoices and everything else. No one is receiving anything. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes you can take a backup using SSH and keep the site running without any issue
- Yes there might be chance the new upgrade module may break the functionality , you could create a staging version and try upgrade first on staging site
- there are several possibilities, Compilation may be enabled , JS/CSS might be merged , there might be some external Caching installed , there might be CDN used that require to purge files from CDN and so on
- If you are not receiving emails , it might be because cron is not setup properly or there might be some third party extension causing this issue or it may be server configuration issue

If is wise to contact some agency working on Magento and get site audit and check if it worth spending money in this upgrade or upgrade/rebuild site in Magento2 will be good option

Comment: How do I add staging sites? Can't seem to find it anywhere? This didn't work: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/system-operations/staging-website-create.html couldnt find it there.

Comment: Also.. my js/css are not merged and there doesnt seem to be an external caching installed, no CDN.

Comment: This staging site reference is more of a content staging on the live site itself , I am talking about create a replica of live site on your server with separate database and run on staging.yourdomain.com or dev.yourdomain.com and then perform the upgrade on that environment before you perform the upgrade on live site